# Finding min date from datetime in excel

Tags: excel, date, datetime, min

sorry I know this is going to sound dumb but I just can't get this function to work (keeps returning 0/Jan 1st 1904).

My data is set out in MMM DD, YYYY HH/MM AM/PM so I custom formatted the data set and the returning value cell to that style. I tried MIN and MINA but still 0. I also tried formatting my data to a "date" style but nothing changed and I still got 0.

The only time I can get the correct answer is when I physically change the contents of the cell to DD/MM/YYYY style manually. Is there a way to get min to work they way my data is currently set out? Conversely, is there a way to change the contents to DD/MM/YYYY without physically typing out each entry?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to use the =DATEVALUE(cell) function. If =min() function isn't working most likely the date has been converted to a text string.
[example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSqlO.png)